# does the code "int a"only statement a variable

Tags: ios

When I write the code "int a",I want to know whether this statement will allocate a new memory for the variable a.

Comment: I appreciate English isn't your first language but please try to use paragraphs and code formatting. I've read this several times and I can't understand it at all

Comment: Do you mean declaring a global variable without initialization vs. with initialization?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am very sorry about my English. the meaning I want to press is whether the code"int a" only statement a variable a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a global variable:

1) go to the .h file

2) type this code: `extern NSInteger MYGlobalVariable`

3) go to the corresponding .m file

4) type this code: `MYGlobalVariable = 0;`    You can place whatever default value you want in place of the zero